# In java how do I put two one-dimensional arrays into one two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, data-structures

Hi everyone this is my first post and I am fairly new to Java. I did search the sites for duplicates before posting this and saw a couple that were similar but not similar enough for me to come up with a working solution from.

I am trying to construct a two-dimensional array double X[][] from two one-dimensional arrays X1[] and X2[].

Previously in the code below is how X1[] and X2[] were initialized in line 10 and line 11 respectively:

```
double[] degree = new double[numNodes];
for (int id = 0; id < numNodes; id++){
    Vector neighbors = (Vector) netInfo.get(id);
    System.out.println(id+" "+neighbors+" "+neighbors.size() );
    degree[id] = neighbors.size();
}

double X1[] = new double[edgeList.size()];
double X2[] = new double[edgeList.size()];
double Y[] = new double[edgeList.size()]; //EBWC which is also 1-NOVER

for (int edgeIndex = 0; edgeIndex < edgeList.size(); edgeIndex++){
    String edge = (String) edgeList.get(edgeIndex);
    StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(edge);
    int uID = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
    int vID = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
    X1[edgeIndex] = degree[uID];
    X2[edgeIndex] = degree[vID];                                                                                  
    Vector uNeighbors = (Vector) netInfo.get(uID);
    Vector vNeighbors = (Vector) netInfo.get(vID);
    // finding the intersection
    Vector commonNeighbors = new Vector();
    for (int uindex = 0; uindex < uNeighbors.size(); uindex++){
        int uNeighbID = ( (Integer) uNeighbors.get(uindex) ).intValue();
        if (vNeighbors.contains(uNeighbID)) {
           commonNeighbors.add(uNeighbID);
        }
        // check if uNeighbID is in vNeighbors
        // if it is there, add uNeighbID to commonNeighbors
    }                                       
    // finding the union
    Vector AllNeighbors = (Vector) uNeighbors.clone();
    //Set<Integer> temp=new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int vindex = 0; vindex < vNeighbors.size(); vindex++){
       //temp.add(i);
       int i = ( (Integer) vNeighbors.get(vindex) ).intValue();
       if (!AllNeighbors.contains(i))
           AllNeighbors.add(i);
    }
    double NOVER = 0;
    if (AllNeighbors.size() > 2)
       NOVER = ( (double) commonNeighbors.size() )/ (AllNeighbors.size()-2);

    Y[edgeIndex] = 1 - NOVER;

    // using the intersection and union, find EBWC scores for the edge uID-vID as 1-NOVER(uID, vID)

    // put uID vID and the EBWC score for the edge to the TreeMap EBWC
   System.out.println(edgeIndex+" "+X1[edgeIndex]+" "+X2[edgeIndex]+" "+Y[edgeIndex]);
}
```

However, my current problem is that the inputs is as follows:
X1      X2
0           1

0           2

1           2

1           5

2           3

2           4

3           4

3           5

4           5

4           6

5           6

5           7

6           7

And my desired output is:

X

0            1

0            2

1            2

1            5

2            3

2            4

3            4

3            5

4            5

4            6

5            6

5            7

6            7

What I tried:

```
// construct the X[][] two-dim array using X1[] and X2[]

double[][] X = {X1, X2};
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < edgeList.size(); rowIndex++){
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 2(); colIndex++){
        System.out.print(X[rowIndex][colIndex]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

However it threw an exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Any ideas, hints, or examples would be greatly appreciated. I want to learn what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the two minutes it takes to **properly** align/indent/format your input; instead of dumping such a (sorry) mess on us.

Comment: Take time and format your code. You obviously haven't taken time you properly display your question, if you can't be bothered to put effort into this question, why should we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] x1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] x2 = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        int[][] y = { x1, x2 };

        for(int i=0;i<y.length;i++){
            for(int k=0;k<y[i].length;k++){
                System.out.println(y[i][k]);
            }
        }
```

here you have a working example. this should help you with your problem